# Edge Animate - Accessing a variable on a symbol's timeline from a different symbol?

Tags: jquery-animate, adobe-edge

I have a stage with several symbols in that need to interact with each other. Each symbol has it's own timeline, writes a variable when it is activated, and subsequently re-writes that variable under certain conditions. That part is fine.

However, I need to access the value of this variable for use in conditional statements, but I can't seem to "point" to where it is. So far I have tried various iterations of:

```
var CrateData = sym.getComposition().getStage().getSymbol("_bl_3x1crate_h").getSymbolElement("_3x1crate").getVariable("Crate1");
```

If I do not use "getSymbolElement" it returns a value of undefined.

```
var CrateData = sym.getComposition().getStage().getSymbol("_bl_3x1crate_h").$("_3x1crate");
```

Gives me a value of Object (I suspect this is closest to what I need it to do)

Answer (score 0):

Solved (kind of). Had to place the variable in a different location and tell it navigate to that location to alter it.

```
var myCrateCheck = sym.getComposition().getStage().getSymbol("_b_2x1crate_h").getVariable("Crate2");

sym.getComposition().getStage().getSymbol("_b_2x1crate_h").setVariable("Crate2", "Moved");
```